# Vertical and horizontal scrollable table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm implementing a time entry web application and the UI has a very tricky scrolling requirement.

Please see sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/yuipcheng/Ek5B2/

The vertical scrollbar is located on the far right. It scrolls all table rows but header and footer.

The horizontal scrollbar is located at the bottom of the table starting from the 4th column to the end. It scrolls all table columns but the first 3 columns.

The first 3 columns may have fixed width (eg 150px).
The 4th to the rest of the columns can have fixed width too but must be much smaller (eg 35px).

All table rows can be the same height and I'm open to both CSS and JavaScript solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put the table inside div....something like

```
<div style="width:XXXpx;height:XXXpx;overflow:auto;">

table goes here

</div>
```

The `overflow:auto` will create the scrollbar when neccessary.

Comment: Where do the header and footer go? Table or Div?

Comment: header before start of div and footer after end of div

Comment: the content inside div only will be within scroll bar. so keep the header and footer outside div.

Comment: @dku.rajkumar It was a test comment I forgot to delete

Comment: Your approach is the same as what ptriek suggested in the demo. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at this solution:

http://www.novasoftware.com/Download/jQuery_FixedTable/jQuery_FixedTable_Demo.htm

(and you could try to Google before asking... :-)

Comment: I did both Google and Bing but couldn't find anything useful and so I asked here. Thanks for the demo link but the horizontal scrollbar is not located at the bottom. I'll try and see if I can fix that.